# PHP fwrite() file leads to internal server error

Tags: php, file, memory, fwrite

i want to upload large files to my server. I splice these files before upload in max. 1MB chunks. If one chunk is uploaded, this chunk gets appended to the file. 
On my local server everything works well, but if i test this script on my Webserver (hosted by Strato -.-) the process quits with an Internal Server Error everytime the appended file on the server gets 64MB large.
I think its (of course?) caused because of a restriction from Strato. Maybe something with the memory but i cant explain to myself why this happens. 
This is the script (PHP version 5.6):

```
$file = $_FILES['chunk'];
$server_chunk = fopen($uploadDir.$_POST['file_id'], "ab");
$new_chunk = fopen($file['tmp_name'], "rb");

while(!feof($new_chunk)) //while-loop is optional
{
     fwrite($server_chunk, fread($new_chunk, 1024));
};
fclose($new_chunk);
fclose($server_chunk);
```

In my opinion there is no line in this code where the file gets loaded in the memory to cause this error or could something different cause this error?

I checked te server-logs but there is no entry if this error happens.

[php.ini](http://kritten.org/test/phpinfo.php)

I can create multiple 63MB files. Only if the files exceed 64MB the server aborts.

**UPDATE:**
I wrote the following script to concatenate the filechunks on the server with cat.
But I always get a 8192B File back.
Is something wrong with this script?
$command is something like:
*/bin/cat ../files/8_0 ../files/8_1 ../files/8_2 ../files/8_3*

```
$command = '/bin/cat';
foreach($file_array AS $file_info)
{
    $command = $command.' ../files/'.$file_info['file_id'].'_'.$file_info['server_chunkNumber'];
}
$handle1 = popen($command, "r");
$read = fread($handle1, $_GET['size']);
echo $read;
```

I checked the result. The bytes in the 8192B file are exactly the same as of the beginning of the original file. So something seems to work...

Update:
I found [this](http://php.timesoft.cc/manual/en/function.popen.php#50408).

Update:

```
$handle1 = popen($command, "r");
while(!feof($handle1))  
{ 
    $read = fread($handle1, 1024);
    echo $read;
}
```

This works, i can piecewise read from the handle. But of course this way im running into timeout limits. How can i pass the file to the client? If this question is answered all of my problems are gone ;)

Comment: Are you able to change your memory size limit?

Comment: Your server use CGI or FastCGI in PHP?

Comment: @EricSSH no i'm not. My Webhoster is really strict ;) But I think thats not the point. I hope there is way to write script, which works on different webhosters without changing anything. That would be great.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento yes i think so. php.ini says: "Server API: CGI/FastCGI"

Comment: @KristofKomlossy post php.ini in your question :)

Comment: Can you create a 65 Mb file by opening a new file and writing 65M zeroes into it? If not, then it's clearly a filesystem limitation. Could it be that you're exceeding your disk quota, and it just happens by chance to hit a "suspicious" number like 64MB? Can you create three 32 Mb files?

Comment: Don't use mysql anymore btw.. use mysqli

Comment: @EricSSH Where do you read "mysql" in question?

Comment: @lserni i cant create a 65MB file. it aborts at size 64MB -.-
i have more than 9GB free space on my server and yes i can create many 34MB files

Comment: @KristofKomlossy Do you have a SpigotMC Jar for built `#1649` of spigot mc :,-(

Answer (score 2):

*(see update at bottom)*

A memory limit error would look different (but you can write a script that continuously allocates memory by adding large objects to a growing array, and see what happens). Also, the memory limit is related to the PHP core, plus script, plus structures, plus any file content; even if a file *appended to* were to be loaded or counted against memory limit (maybe through `mmap`, even if it appears weird), it is unlikely at best that the limit should chance at 64 megabytes.

So this looks like **a filesystem limitation on a single file size** to me. There are several cloud file systems that have such limitations; but I know of none such on a local disk storage. I'd ask clues to the hosting tech support.

Some attempts that I'd make:

- double check `$uploadDir` unless it was assigned by you personally.
- try creating the file in a different path than `$uploadDir`, unless certainly on the same filesystem
- try checking for errors:

  ```
  if (!fwrite($server_chunk, fread($new_chunk, 1024))) {
     die("Error writing: ");
  }
  ```
- paranoid check on phpinfo() to ensure there isn't some really *weird* weirdness such as [function overriding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php). You can investigate by [enumerating the functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php) and checking them out (*spoofable, yes, but unlikely to have been*).

## UPDATE

**it REALLY looks like a filesize limitation, unrelated to PHP**. Earlier users of the same hosting reported 32 Mb. See [here](http://uweschmelzer.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/strato-filesize-limit-30-mb/) and [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-overcome-hosting-provider-strato-php-limits). There's people unable to run `mysqldump`, or `tar` backups. It has nothing to do with PHP directly.

## Workaround... which seems to work!

You can perhaps work around this problem by storing the file in chunks, and downloading it in several installments or by passing Apache a pipe to the `cat` program, if available.

What would happen is that you would store file123.0001, file123.0002, ..., and then upon download check all the fragments, send the appropriate `Content-Length`, build a commandline for `/bin/cat` (*if accessible...*) and connect the stream to the server. You may still run into time limits, but it's worth a shot.

Example:

```
<?php
    $pattern    = "test/zot.*"; # BEWARE OF SHELL METACHARACTERS
    $files      = glob($pattern);
    natsort($files);
    $size       = array_sum(array_map('filesize', $files));
    ob_end_clean();
    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"test.bin\";");
    Header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    Header("Content-Length: {$size}");
    passthru("/bin/cat {$pattern}");
```

I have tested the above and it downloads a single 120Mb file from a bunch of 10-Mb chunks, ordered like zot.1, zot.2, ..., zot.10, zot.11, zot.12 (*and yes, I did not use `natsort` at first*). If I can find the time I'll run it again in a VM with throttled network, so that the script has 10s time limit and the download would take 20s. It's *possible* that PHP **won't terminate the script until passthru returns**, since I noticed PHP's timekeeping is not very intuitive.

The following code runs with a time limit of **three seconds**. It runs a command that takes *four* seconds, then sends the output to the browser, keeps running until its time is exhausted.

```
<pre>
<?php
    print "It is now " . date("H:i:s") . "\n";
    passthru("sleep 4; echo 'Qapla!'");
    print "It is now " . date("H:i:s") . "\n";
    $x = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $t = microtime(true);
        while (microtime(true) < $t + 1.0) {
            $x++;
        }
        echo "OK so far. It is now " . date("H:i:s") . "\n";
    }
```

The result is:

```
It is now 20:52:56
Qapla!
It is now 20:53:00
OK so far. It is now 20:53:01
OK so far. It is now 20:53:02
OK so far. It is now 20:53:03


( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded in /srv/www/rumenta/htdocs/test.php on line 9

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  235384  {main}( )   ../test.php:0
2   7.0191  236152  microtime ( )   ../test.php:9
```

Of course, it is possible that Strato uses a stronger check on a script's running time. Also, I have PHP installed as a module; possibly for CGIs, which run as independent processes, different rules apply.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer. I already tried to store the files in chunks and download the chunks with readfile() earlier. But the script was running in the time limit (120sec) as you said. You say I have to try to store the file in chunks on the server? There is no other possibility to avoid the strato restriction? And maybe the uplaod will work well with other hosters? great -.- I will try your advice with cat and will be back soon ;)

Comment: Does this from php info help: `post_max_size 48M`, `post_max_size 48M`

Comment: I've run some promising experiments :-)

Comment: @lserni I tried it with passthru() but its still running into the time limit. php.net says: "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends." How do i do that? Is there any way to get out of the php process? maybe to sned the cat command with php and let the server after the cat process download the file. dont know ;)

Comment: No, if you redirected the stream it wouldn't help you. And it's not possible from PHP to connect the child process (cat) with the parent (web server) and quietly die leaving them work. I'm afraid you'll have to bring this up with Strato.

Comment: So as a conclusion there is NO way to write a script in any language for uploading and downloading large files?

Comment: There are several ways, but apparently Strato prevents them. You can try disabling time limit using `set_time_limit`. But chances are that this, too, has been forbidden.