# Writing to bigger files leads to Internal Server Error

Tags: php, file, upload, internal-server-error

Implementing a feature for uploading files with a (potentially) unlimited filesize using chunked-file uploading and WebWorkers, I stumbled upon a quite strange problem:

Whenever I try to attempt to write to a file bigger than `128 MB - 134 MB` using `fwrite()`, an internal Server error is raised and, thus, script execution is stopped. The problem could be simplified to this (hopefully self-explanatory) test-case:

```
$readHandle = fopen("smallFile", "r"); // ~ 2 MB
$writeHandle = fopen("bigFile", "a");  // ~ 134 MB

// First possible way of writing data to the file:
// If the file size of bigFile is at approx. 134 MB, this
// will result in an HTTP 500 Error.

while (!feof($readHandle)){
    fwrite($writeHandle, fread($readHandle, 1024 * 1024));
}

// Second way of reproducing the problem:
// Here, the data is just NOT written to the destination
// file, but the script itself doesn't crash.

// stream_copy_to_stream($readHandle, $writeHandle);

fclose($readHandle);
fclose($writeHandle);
```

When using `stream_copy_to_stream`, the script doesn't crash, but the data is just not written to the destination file.

Having contacted the support-team of my (shared) server host, I got the answer that this limit had something to do with the php configuration variables `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size`. However, neither do the set values (`96MB` for both) correspond to the measured maximum file size (`134MB`) at which files are writeable, nor does the problem exist when I apply the same values to my local test server.

Also, I could not find any information about a potential correlation between `PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT` (the offer I am using states `512MB`) and the maximum writeable file size of `128 - 134MB` (of which `512MB` is a multiple).

Does anybody know if

1. the said configuration values really correspond to the problem at all?
2. there is any other way of continuing appending data to such a file?

PS: [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000277/php-fwrite-file-leads-to-internal-server-error) might be based on the same problem, but here the question(s) are different.

Comment: Do you see an error message or a white page? At the beginning of the file add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if you get a better error message.

Comment: Enabling maximum error reporting doesn't Show more Information; just the same `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, support@foobar.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
`